# What means "methods without access control can be declared more private in subclasses" in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, access-modifiers

In java access modifiers and inheritance topic says below 4 points. What does "**more private**" mean in 3rd point ?

1. ...
2. ...
3. Methods declared without access control => can be declared **more private** in subclasses
4. ...

Comment: Read: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: It's **WRONG**. You **can't** redeclare an inherited method to be more private than it was in the base class: only more public.

Comment: @EJB I also thought same, so the inherited should be made **public** right ?

Comment: the inherited *can* be made public.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

([This has a translation in Russian on RU.SO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432255/181472))

There's actually no such term as 'more' or 'less private'. Instead 'more / less visible' is used.

**The statement in the question is wrong**. A method cannot be made less visible as that would break the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle):

> Let Φ(x) be a property provable about objects x of type T. Then Φ(y) should be true for objects y of type S where S is a subtype of T.

Here's a repo on GitHub that illustrates all possible variants with inheritance of a package-access method in Java.
https://github.com/NickVolynkin/PackageAccessTest

```
public class Parent {

    //package access
    void foo() {
    }
}

public class ChildPublic extends Parent {

    // Legal
    @Override
    public void foo() {
    }
}

public class ChildProtected extends Parent {
    // Legal
    @Override
    protected void foo() {
    }
}

public class ChildPrivate extends Parent {
    // Illegal
    /*
    @Override
    private void foo() {
    }
    */
}

public class SamePackageAccessTest {
    {
        new Parent().foo();

        //these have overriden foo()
        new ChildPublic().foo();
        new ChildProtected().foo();

        //this one had not overriden foo()
        new ChildPrivate().foo();
    }
}

package otherpackage;
import test.*;
public class OtherPackageAccessTest {

    {
        //Legal!
        new ChildPublic().foo();

        //illegal
        /*
        new ParentPackage().foo();
        new ChildProtected().foo();
        new ChildPrivate().foo();
        */

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Methods declared without access control => can be declared more private in subclasses

It is **WRONG.** This is exactly the reverse of the case. Methods declared with any level of access control must be overridden with that level or a more public level: in this case, the access level base class is 'default', so you can override with `public` or `protected.`

Contrary to what the Google documentation says, you *cannot* override with `private.` See [JLS §8.4.8.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.3):

> The access modifier (§6.6) of an overriding or hiding method must provide at least as much access as the overridden or hidden method, as follows:
>
> - If the overridden or hidden method is `public,` then the overriding or hiding method must be `public;` otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
> - If the overridden or hidden method is `protected,` then the overriding or hiding method must be `protected` or `public;` otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.
> - If the overridden or hidden method has package access, then the overriding or hiding method must not be `private;` otherwise, a compile-time error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Full information can be found in this [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Methods declared without access control can be redefined (overridden is not quite the correct word here) in child classes that are not in the same package.

```java
package p1;
public class A {
    void m() {}
}


package p1;
public class B {
    //This does not work as class is in the same package and this would be an attempt to reduce visibility
    private void m() {}
}


package p2;
public class C extends A {
    //This works fine as class C does not 'see' the parent method
    private void m() {
    }
}
```

Comment: Which is not 'more private'.

Comment: True, the original formulation is awful. Not 'more private', just 'private'.

Comment: It's not 'private' either. `protected` is more *public.* The statement in the Google documentation is just plain wrong.